# Default action of INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on MsSQL DB

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've got problem with INSTEAD OF trigger in MsSQL. I got an app with some error, and as a quick workaround I don't want user to modify one exact row in DB.
I created following trigger: (on table)

```
 create trigger UglyWorkaround ON Configuration instead of update 
  as
    begin
        if (select COUNT(1) from inserted where Key='Key01' and Value<>'2') > 0 begin
            update Configuration set Value='2' where Key='Key01'
        end else begin
            -- DEFAULT ACTION (do update as intended)
        end;


    end;
```

But I've got problem with determining, how to set default action.
`Update Configuration set Value=inserted.Value where Key=inserted.Key` doesn't work for me. Is there any way how to do this with triggers? (I know that the solution is bad, but I got no other option, as I can't change code now.)

Comment: You say you **don't** want to modify a specific row but your code changes `Value` when `Key='Key01'`.

Comment: It changes the Value back in case user changed it to other value than I want. Maybe I didn't understood the principle of triggers well

Comment: @Yossarian, you are using an `instead of update` trigger, so SQL Server won't be updating that row, and you don't need to worry about changing it back.

Comment: @adrift, Oh. I'm such an idiot. Thanks for kicking me the good way :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inserted` is a table, so try joining:

```
update c set c.Value = i.Value
from Configuration c
    inner join inserted i on c.Key = i.Key
```

You could also filter out `Key01` at the same time, and it wouldn't matter if they tried to update the value for `Key01` to something other than `2`.

```
update c set c.Value = i.Value
from Configuration c
    inner join inserted i on c.Key = i.Key
where i.Key <> 'Key01'
```

Answer (score 1):

The INSTEAD OF part means that you're going to have to update the other columns as well as the value one.

There's no need to do this with an if .. else as the logic can be done at column level

```
create trigger NicerWorkaround ON Configuration instead of update 
as
begin

update c set 
c.Value = CASE WHEN i.Key='Key01' THEN '2' ELSE i.Value END,
c.OtherColumn1 = i.OtherColumn1,
c.OtherColumn2 = i.OtherColumn2
from Configuration c
inner join inserted i on c.Key = i.Key    
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the edit perform a `rollback` on the change, why are you setting `Value='2'` when you find a matching row?

You don't have to supply a default action, doing nothing in the trigger will let the update happen.

Comment: This is an INSTEAD OF trigger as opposed to an AFTER one